# How can I copy hex from Visual Studio's binary editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, hex

I'm comparing two bitmap files in Visual Studio's binary editor and I'd like to annotate a copy of them with the various [parts of the bitmap header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) that I think each byte sequence forms. Here's how the files look in Visual Studio:

[image: screenshot]

How can I copy-and-paste the hex rendering, rather than the byte values themselves, from Visual Studio's Binary Editor to another program (e.g. Notepad)?

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Studio's binary file editor does not have this functionality, and they have no intention of enhancing this tool. Try HxD or XVI32. (Although I can feel your disappointment, [tools recommendation is out of scope for Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211269/why-stackoverflow-doesnt-allow-comparison-questions-or-recommendations-for-tool).)

Comment: Tool recommendation may not be in scope for questions, but I think they are allowed as "try this instead" adjuncts to answers? Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Why not make that a proper answer, mates?

Comment: @rwong How do you know they have no intention of fixing it?  I see that it's still an issue, so you may be right.

Comment: @RobertBernstein There are certain parts of VS that's already grandfathered. [Try VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905181/how-do-i-see-a-bin-file-in-a-hex-editor-in-visual-studio-code).

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [commandline dumphex tool](https://github.com/clovett/tools/tree/master/dumphex) which produces the same output ...