# How do I see a bin file in a hex editor in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hex-editors

I have a bin file holding all my instruction cache and data cache for my Verilog project, and I want to see it as the Notepad++ hex editor shows its meaning, hex representation view. Is there a way to configure this?

Or maybe an extension that provides this functionality?

Comment: Asking for external links is off topic.  Besides, it's easy to find [an extension for vscode that does what you want](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-hexdump)

Comment: no i tried that extension and it doesnt let me see a .bin file
also if you have a way to make it work without external extension 
it will be much better

Comment: You want https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-hexdump

Comment: 10x but as i said before it translate string to hex format and not a bin file .
also it cant process big files (6mb)

Answer (score 67):

VSCode 1.46 (May 2020) will have its own [native Hex Editor extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d5787d62216069e0b66b77c9470bb2d093c60e59/release-notes/v1_46.md#hex-editor):

> ### Hex Editor
>
> With the custom editor API finalized with support for binary editors, we have developed a [hex editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor) to provide a native hex editing experience.

[image: https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_46/hex-editor.gif]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't necessarily solve the problem of viewing a binary file as it doesn't work if the file isn't writable.

Comment: @JesperMatthiesen I did not realize that. A possible workaround would be to copy/duplicate the file, taking ownership and making that copy writable.

Answer (score 58):

1. Install this extension: *[Hexdump for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-hexdump)*. It can display a specified file in hexadecimal.
2. Open the file/image/whatever you want to display in hex mode in Visual Studio Code, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then input `Show hexdump from path` to open a file in hex mode directly.

Comment: Thanks for including the magic keys.  I had already installed the extension, but had no idea how to activate it.

Comment: hex dump is good, but it really suffers with larger files and does not allow editing. Is there anything like that?

Comment: How do I copy the hex dump without getting stuff like line number and the preview to the right of the hex dump?

Comment: Hexdump is deprecated. They suggest using [Hex Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor) by microsoft.

Comment: this extension is deprecated. Use Hex Editor of VS Code.

Answer (score 8):

Hexdump has been deprecated. The alternative right now is Hex Editor by Microsoft.

[Hex Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor)
OR
`ext install ms-vscode.hexeditor`

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [Hex Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor)
2. Then open the file you want to edit in **VS Code**
3. It will say you cannot open the file in here (if it's binary file), Select **Open Anyway**
   [image]
4. Select **Hex Editor** from the Command Panel
   [image]
5. You should see something similar to this:
   [image]